# I'm trying to use fixtures to hold data for different tests, This is an example of the code. where I'm getting 'Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: cypress

I'm trying to use fixtures to hold data for different tests, This is an example of the code. When it gets to the second test I'm getting 'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')'.

```js
/// <reference types="Cypress" />

describe('MyFirstTestSuite', () => {

    before(() => {
        // root-level hook
        // runs once before all tests
        cy.fixture('example').then(function(data) { 
          this.data=data
        });
      });

    it('FirstTest case', () => {
        cy.visit('https://rahulshettyacademy.com/angularpractice/')
        cy.get('').type(this.data.name)
        cy.get('Select').select(this.data.gender)  
    });
});
```

And here is my environment.json file:

```js
{
  "name" : "Darshit",
  "gender": "Male"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

> this.data=data

try using

> globalThis.data = data

Comment: Please consider editing your answer to adding a reason why this works. Explain what issue OP had and why your solution solves that problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It solves my problem when I use 'globalThis.data = data' instead of 'this.data'. 
At this moment I'm using 'globalThis.data = data' and didn't face any problem no matter how may 'IT' blocks I have and I can use this value globally

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the `this` keyword, you'll need to define `data` somewhere. Additionally, you'll need to use a [traditional function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this) because arrow functions do not have a `this` binding. You can easily accomplish this by using `.as()`. [Filip Hric goes over different solutions in this blog post.](https://filiphric.com/cypress-basics-variables)

```js
describe('MyFirstTestSuite', () => {

    before(() => {
        // root-level hook
        // runs once before all tests
        cy.fixture('example').as('data'); // change this to using an alias
      });

    it('FirstTest case', function() { // change this because `this` does not work with arrow functions
        cy.visit('https://rahulshettyacademy.com/angularpractice/')
        cy.get('').type(this.data.name)
        cy.get('Select').select(this.data.gender)  
    });
});
```

[Cypress has more information on fixtures here.](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/as#Fixture)

Comment: Thank you for the response,


 i have tried this please find below mentioned details, but this is not working for me.

before(() => {
        // root-level hook
        // runs once before all tests
        cy.fixture('example').as('data'); // change this to using an alias
      });


        it('Verify user is able to submit the form', () => {
        cy.visit(Cypress.env('POCurl'))
        cy.get('input[name = "name"]:nth-child(2)').type(as.data.name)
        cy.get('Select').select(as.data.gender)

Comment: `.as()` is just used to let Mocha know that we're aliasing this value. You should still reference the variables by `this.` => `this.data.name` instead of `as.data.name`